# Rails 4 - Heroku - production errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm new to coding and learning on the go. I find it difficult to decipher what the heroku logs are telling me. I just tried to push the master branch to heroku and got an error directing me to the logs. The logs say the following. I can barely understand the english let alone make out what it might mean.

Can anyone see the problem I need to focus on to fix this?

```
heroku logs
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086023+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rolify-5.0.0/lib/rolify/dynamic.rb:13:in `load_dynamic_methods'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086022+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086028+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rolify-5.0.0/lib/rolify.rb:33:in `rolify'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086030+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086043+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086044+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086046+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086048+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086061+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086049+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086062+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086067+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086069+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086080+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086081+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:302:in `get'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in `to'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086085+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in `modules'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086087+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:92:in `routes'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086089+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:159:in `default_used_route'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086101+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in `initialize'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086102+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `new'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086103+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `add_mapping'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086104+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in `block in devise_for'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086105+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086107+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086109+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/routes.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086126+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086127+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086111+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086123+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086124+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086125+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086132+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086130+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086143+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086144+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086145+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086148+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:170:in `reload_routes!'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086152+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086167+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086147+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086168+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086150+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:14:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086169+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086154+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086173+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086175+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086177+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086172+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:55:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086205+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086210+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086179+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086181+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086213+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086213+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086215+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086215+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086217+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086217+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086220+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086222+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086221+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086240+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086224+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086241+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086245+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086241+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086244+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086248+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086251+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086247+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086270+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086263+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086266+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086264+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086264+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086267+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086270+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086284+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086272+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2016-03-25T08:20:22.133222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-25T08:20:22.119281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-25T08:22:00.423386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.cttr.com request_id=3311cef7-19ae-4309-8020-53f88bcb630f fwd="49.191.132.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-25T08:22:01.417500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.cttr.com request_id=cd78c604-f5e3-48d5-9bd7-f974b7f61da4 fwd="49.191.132.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-25T08:25:54.618347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.cttr.com request_id=4fb1a6ed-3ef6-48f7-b1a5-fde8200b2529 fwd="49.191.132.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-25T08:25:55.206739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.cttr.com request_id=dc0d2a42-9937-4a4a-9815-d3c520951ef8 fwd="49.191.132.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-25T08:31:51.288633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.cttr.com request_id=b3b64814-3915-47f3-9032-30d8cdf4c0ec fwd="49.191.132.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-25T08:31:51.957639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.cttr.com request_id=c85281e9-1c34-474f-a153-ebe5085c11f6 fwd="49.191.132.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `--tail` option to your command:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

It will give you full real-time logs, not only a bit. May be real reason will be shown in real-time logs. Just run logs with tail and try to open crashing page and find bug in logs that received just now.

2. Some lines in your log contains paths to your project file, I marked them bold:

```
heroku logs
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086023+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rolify-5.0.0/lib/rolify/dynamic.rb:13:in `load_dynamic_methods'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086022+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086028+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user.rb:2:in `'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rolify-5.0.0/lib/rolify.rb:33:in `rolify'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086030+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `'
2016-03-25T08:20:21.086042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
...
```

Look these files at specified rows, may be bug is somewhere here.